# Rearrange the tuple by sorting in python

Tags: python, sorting, arraylist

I have two lists. One list contains X coordinate values and second list contains Y coordinate values. Using these two lists, I want to make a tupple which is sorted by their first element.

```
X coordinate = [2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
Y coordinate = [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

I want my output like this:

```
[(0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

To achieve this result, I wrote below code and got an output mentioend below.

```
merged_list = list(tuple(zip(X3_coordinate, Y3_coordinate)))
merged_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
merged_list
```

Output:

```
[(0, 4), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong and give some suggestions of code.

Comment: simple `merged_list.sort()` will do, tuple comparison is already done element-wise

Comment: Thank you for your comment and guidance. This code works well. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- instead of `list(tuple())` just do `list()`
- sort with no key, it'll do element-wise by default
- use `sorted` do both generate the list and sort

```
X_coordinate = [2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
Y_coordinate = [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2]
merged_list = sorted(zip(X_coordinate, Y_coordinate))
print(merged_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and guidance. This code works well. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello @arzo, would you please check my latest question? It is related to sorting the nodes but in more aligned order such that every consecutive nodes placed next to each other. I am stuck at that problem. Kindly give some suggestions on that. Thank you

Comment: What should I do if I have to place two consecutive nodes ( node number 2 & node number 3 or node number 4 & node number 5)  next to eachother.

Answer (score 2):

You've sorted by x, but not later by y:

```
merged_list.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))

[(0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and guidance. This code works well. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What should I do if I have to place two consecutive nodes ( node number 2 & node number 3 or node number 4 & node number 5) next to eachother.

Answer (score 1):

By using "key=lambda x: x[0]", you are forcing it to be sorted only by the first element, what you seek is a sort where-in you give priority to the first element, but if the values are same you wish to sort it by the subsequent elements.

```
X3_coordinate = [2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
Y3_coordinate = [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2]
merged_list = list(zip(X3_coordinate, Y3_coordinate))
merged_list.sort()
print(merged_list)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and guidance. This code works well. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello Mr. Gupta, would you please check my latest question? It is related to sorting the nodes but in more aligned order such that every consecutive nodes placed next to each other. I am stuck at that problem. Kindly give some suggestions on that. Thank you

Comment: What should I do if I have to place two consecutive nodes ( node number 2 & node number 3 or node number 4 & node number 5) next to eachother.